# Get space quota Live SDK One Drive

Tags: android, onedrive, live-sdk

I am developing an android application based on One Drive, using the Live SDK. I am stuck on how to get the available and free space for each user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From REST, you can get quota and available space for the current signed in user with ([details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659731.aspx#get_a_user_s_total_and_remaining_onedrive_storage_quota))

```
GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/quota?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

which returns JSON

```
{ "quota": 26843545600,
  "available": 26805319016 }
```

So, for Android, based on [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659734.aspx) you can probably just use something like this for this GET call

```
client.getAsync("me/skydrive/quota", new LiveOperationListener() {
... });
```